# Icons are showing as some special characters on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, icons

All the icons are replaced with these special characters showing on the screen as shown in the below image but on refreshing page icons appears again why is this happening.

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBfgL.png)